# Ubuntu 18 server IPV6 connectivity

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

After 2 days of headbanging, i really need help!

I've installed Ubuntu 18 Server and trying to allocate a public IPV6 address which is a /64 block.

However, no matter what i do i seem to hit a brick wall and get the following error when i ping any remote ipv6 address: "**connect: Network is unreachable**"

Im also unable to ping the gateway6 address from the server but the same ip is pingable from another server just fine.

During debugging i have reloaded the server with Windows and Centos7, Both worked perfectly fine using the same IP Values so this is definetly related to how im configuring Ubuntu with IPV6.

Here is my current netplan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses: [ "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24", "2a04:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::1/64" ]
      gateway4: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      gateway6: "2a04:zzzz:zzzz:zzzz::1"
      nameservers:
          addresses:
              - "2001:4860:4860::8888"
              - "8.8.8.8"
```

**Here is the output from "ip -a"**

```
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/24 brd xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx scope global ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a04:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any help will be a huge releif!

Comment: "connect: Network is unreachable" is a message from the router that it does not know how to reach the network. What does the hosting server routing table look like? Does it have a route to that network?

Comment: Ron, do you mean the ESXI host which hosts the VM?  Ubuntu shows that message when ever i try to ping any IPV6 address such as google or any remote address... The only address that resolves and pings is the address i declare in /etc/netplan config but that ipv6 address is not accessible from a remote source... It seems Ubuntu is not configured with IPV6 properly?

Comment: If i assign the IPV6 /64 block to the windows VM it works perfectly but does not work on the ubuntu VM

Comment: Remember that ping, like many other things, is bidirectional. Depending on where you are when you get that message, it means that a router between you and the destination is sending back an ICMP error message because it does not know how to reach that network. Please explain from where you are trying to ping.

Comment: Are you actually assigning the entire network to a VM? That seems pointless because a host only needs the single address to be reached and use the network. Remember that just because you use the `/64` on the address does not mean you are assigning the whole network. It is just like a mask on an IPv4 address,

Comment: I have a /46 for the dedicated machine (ESXI Host) and then im giving each VM its own /64... I believe ive taken the correct steps and if i use the exact same values on the windows VM it works fine and the windows machine is given the /64 range

Comment: I think the ping might be confusing because the ping only works on the VM which is assigned the IP address so for example it would be like:  ping 127.0.0.1 because its not leaving the machine... If i ping that IP from a remote machine it wont work but if i assign that ip to the windows VM with the exact same values.... then it can be reached and pinged from any remote machine and everything works fine... This is most likely ubuntu related and ive not setup ipv6 properly on ubuntu.

Comment: If you are assigning `2a04:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::1/64`, you are actually assigning a single address (just like assigning an IPv4 <address> <mask>, except IPv6 uses the mask length, not an explicit mask). Also, remember that all addresses in a network, even the zero address, are valid host addresses in IPv6, so even assigning `2a04:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::/64` is assigning a single address.

Comment: By the way, IANA has set aside prefixes for both IPv4 and IPv6 to be use for address examples so that you can use realistic addresses, and everyone will know they are example addresses. For IPv4 (three ranges): `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`. For IPv6 (one range): `2001:db8::/32`. You can subnet those any way you want, not give away real addressing, and be realistic in your example addressing.

Comment: Yeah, so far things have worked ok regarding windows vm's its the Ubuntu server causing me the headaches... For example here is what ive done to each of the windows VMs...    WIN VM1:  2a04:0000:0000:0001::1/64  ----  WIN VM2:  2a04:0000:0000:0002::1/64  ----  WIN VM2:  2a04:0000:0000:0003::1/64  and they all work fine... i know i might not be explaining everything technically perfect because im still learning :-)

Comment: @RonMaupin - If you would be willing to provide help privately I would be happy to pay the service.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work that way here, and I am really a network guy, not a server guy. The server guys here should chime in soon. I was just trying to give you the network perspective.

Comment: @RonMaupin - No problem i appreciate the help, i have just installed a CentOS server and followed the same steps as i have with Ubuntu and it works perfectly so this is isolated to Ubuntu... i must be setting IPV6 up incorrectly with Ubuntu